# How do I choose a correct Epsilon for computing ray intersections?

Tags: c++, graphics

Good day,

I am trying to compute if a ray hits a plane and then a triangle for my ray tracer. I do not know how to choose an epsilon value to account for floating point errors. Triangles can get pretty small and some of them are missed by my rays.

```
struct Ray {
    glm::vec3 origin { 0.0f };
    glm::vec3 direction { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };
    float t { std::numeric_limits<float>::max() };
};

struct Plane {
    float D = 0.0f;
    glm::vec3 normal { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
};

bool pointInTriangle(const glm::vec3& v0, const glm::vec3& v1, const glm::vec3& v2, const glm::vec3& n, const glm::vec3& p)
{
    Plane plane = trianglePlane(v0,v1,v2);
    if (glm::dot(plane.normal, p) - plane.D == 0)
    {   
        std::cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << std::endl;
        float area0 = glm::length(glm::cross(v0 - v1, v0 - v2)) / 2;
        float a1 = glm::length(glm::cross(v2 - v1, p - v1)) / 2 / area0;
        float a2 = glm::length(glm::cross( v0 - v2, p - v2)) / 2 / area0; 
        float a3 = glm::length(glm::cross(v1 - v0, p - v0)) / 2 / area0;
        if (a1 < 0)
            return false;
        if (a2 < 0)
            return false;
        if (a3 < 0)
            return false;
        if (a1 + a2 + a3 > 1)
            return false;
        if (a1 + a2 + a3 < 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool intersectRayWithPlane(const Plane& plane, Ray& ray)
{
    float t = (plane.D - glm::dot(ray.origin, plane.normal)) / glm::dot(plane.normal, ray.direction);
    if (t <= 0)
        return false;
    if (t < ray.t)
    {
        
        if (glm::dot((ray.origin + ray.direction * t), plane.normal) - plane.D == 0)
        {
            ray.t = t;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this "epsilon" value trying to account for? Are you getting one object appearing in front of another when it shouldn't? If so, maybe the problem is to put more space between them.

Comment: I'd ask the question differently: What should be the maximum distance from a triangle you want to count the ray hitting it even if it is outside? This distance would determine your epsilon...

Comment: There is no one correct _"epsilon"_.  The value you choose is always relative to the numbers being compared.  Eg when comparing numbers close to `1` you might choose an epsilon of `0.000001`; but when comparing numbers close to `1,000,000` you might choose an epsilon of `1.0`.

Comment: [Watertight Ray/Triangle Intersection](https://jcgt.org/published/0002/01/05/)